# Not found: 'dart:ui' in dart scripts (not Flutter)

Tags: dart

I've got a simple Dart script (**not Flutter**) which needs to use the [`dart:ui` core library](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries), e.g.

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  const color = Color(0xFF9585E5);
  print(color);
}
```

From the [get dart](https://dart.dev/get-dart) docs:

> *Note:* The Flutter SDK includes the full Dart SDK, and has Dart’s dart command-line interface in its bin folder.

I try to run it using Android Studio (as a Dart CLI app), and also via command line: `/opt/flutter/bin/dart lib/bin/example_script.dart`. Unfortunately, I get an error:

[image]

### Error:

```
lib/bin/example_script.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
lib/bin/example_script.dart:4:17: Error: Method not found: 'Color'.
  const color = Color(0xFF9585E5);
                ^^^^^
```

I have confirmed I have the latest Flutter, which provides Dart `2.18.4`, which contains `/opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/io/io.dart`.

There are lots of seemingly-related answers, but relevant to **Flutter** apps. I'm writing a dart script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After getting stuck on this for a while...*

`dart:ui` is not a Dart core library, you won't find it in ["Dart core libraries"](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries), so it is not available in dart packages. This was confusing to me because the name sounds like a core library. I was confusing it with `dart:io`

As per [`dart:UI` library docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html):

> Built-in types and core primitives for a **Flutter** application.

I confirmed that `dart:ui` is provided in `/opt/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/ui.dart` (Sky Engine being the old name for Flutter), not the Dart SDK (`/opt/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`). So it seems like it's **only available in Flutter**.

Comment: I am getting the same issue in one of my local dependency after upgrading to flutter 3.7.9. How did you fix this issue ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's related to this question. Perhaps there have been some APIs that were removed (breaking changes), take a look at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes.

Comment: I could not fix any breaking change. In fact my code runs but this error appears when I try to run a script.